# OpenVPN routing across AWS regions

Tags: amazon-vpc, openvpn

I have an AWS account with a VPC in Ireland and another in Sydney, which are connected via VPC peering.

I have 2 Windows servers, one in Ireland, one in Sydney, both are in a Private Subnet. From a server in Ireland I can RDP to the server in Sydney using it's private address, therefore my VPC peer is working.

To connect to the Ireland server, I have an OpenVPN server in the public subnet which I connect the OpenVPN client on my client machine.  Once connected, I can RDP to the Ireland server.  All good.

I am trying to connect to the Sydney server from my client machine, using the route client --> Ireland --> VPC link --> Sydney.

I have pushed routes via my OpenVPN config which means, when I ping the Sydney server, it now goes via the VPN instead of my home router but times out after the first hop.

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert -d 10.150.224.50

Tracing route to 10.150.224.50 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    26 ms    25 ms    25 ms  10.41.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I am at a loss of what happens after that hop, there is also a possibility that I have some config missing in OpenVPN.  Any help / guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do what you want in AWS.

This is an invalid configuration, as per [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html):

## Edge to edge routing through a gateway or private connection

If either VPC in a peering relationship has one of the following connections, you cannot extend the peering relationship to that connection:

- A VPN connection or an AWS Direct Connect connection to a corporate network
- An internet connection through an internet gateway
- An internet connection in a private subnet through a NAT device
- A gateway VPC endpoint to an AWS service; for example, an endpoint to Amazon S3.

For example, if VPC A and VPC B are peered, and VPC A has any of these connections, then instances in VPC B cannot use the connection to access resources on the other side of the connection. Similarly, resources on the other side of a connection cannot use the connection to access VPC B.

[image]

You have two options:

- Configure your OpenVPN server to do NATing instead of routing and therefore "hide" the real source IP of the connection
- Create another VPN connection with another OpenVPN server in Sydney region